How can I integrate stripe with flutter frontend and php backend?
I want to use my own payment form to process payments using flutter frontend and php backend. The form will be created with the following fields: amount, card holder name, card number, expiry date, cvv and a submit button in flutter. I dont want to use stripe's payment form.
I have created an account with stripe and have the publishable and secret keys. ( test account)
Now when I click the submit button after the form has been filled up I want to create a stripe token (which uses the publishable key) and send the token details to my php backend, which will then process the payment and return / success /error codes. The php backend will use the secret key provided by stripe.
Is it possible to do this. I am do so using javascript and php library from stripe in our web application.
If you could guide me as to how to do this it will be of great help. Is this the right way to use your own payment form for flutter / php

Yes, use the stripe_payment package or similar.
For example:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stripe_payment/stripe_payment.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: PaymentPage(),
    );
  }
}

class PaymentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PaymentPageState createState() => _PaymentPageState();
}

class _PaymentPageState extends State<PaymentPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Stripe setup
    StripePayment.setOptions(
      StripeOptions(
        publishableKey: "your_publishable_key", // Publishable key
        androidPayMode: 'test', // For the test environment
      ),
    );
  }

  void processPayment(String amount) async {
    // Create a payment token
    StripePayment.paymentRequestWithCardForm(
      CardFormPaymentRequest(),
    ).then((paymentMethod) {
      // Send token to server
      sendTokenToServer(paymentMethod.id, amount);
    }).catchError((e) {
      print("Error: $e");
    });
  }

  void sendTokenToServer(String token, String amount) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://your-backend-url.com/process_payment.php'),
      body: {
        'token': token,
        'amount': amount,
      },
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print("Payment Successful!");
    } else {
      print("Payment Failed!");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Payment")),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            processPayment("5000"); // Payment amount
          },
          child: Text("Pay Now"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

in PHP and Code in process_payment.php:
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('your_secret_key'); // secret key

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $token = $_POST['token'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount']; // Amount in cents (eg $50 -> 5000)

    try {
        // Create payment
        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
            'amount' => $amount,
            'currency' => 'usd',
            'description' => 'Test Payment',
            'source' => $token,
        ]);

        echo json_encode(['status' => 'success', 'charge' => $charge]);
    } catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException $e) {
        echo json_encode(['status' => 'error', 'message' => $e-            
>getMessage()]);
    }
}
?>

Use the official Stripe SDK for PHP.

thanks for the help.. let me try flutter frontend and do this

Hi  I could not find any package called "stripe_payment" package on pub.dev. Could you please  give a link to that

There's a community built flutter library called flutter_stripe. You might want to integrate it in your Flutter app. https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe

You can also use tihs package : flutter_stripe_payment
